# x64 Word 2010 Add In registration using WiX

Tags: ms-word, wix, vsto, com-interop

I' deploying a Word Add in using WiX, regarding x84 target Platforms (at least the Office installation has to be x86, never the less which OS Platform is used) everything is working well, my COM Interop registration of the Word Add In works and the add in auto-starts the first time I start word afer I installed the Add In.

I'm doing following registration stuff to the registry (cut from output of heat.exe)

I've created an intermediate file, helping me out for the COM Interop registration using this heat command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin\heat.exe" file MyAddin.dll -ag -template fragment -out MyAddin.wxs
```

The output of interesst looks like: (I know using RegistryValue this way has been deprecated)

```
<Class Id="{10BC65F1-32C0-3ED4-98A0-17661A8C4455}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="MyAddin.MyAddinClass" ThreadingModel="both" ForeignServer="mscoree.dll">
    <ProgId Id="MyAddin.MyAddinClass" Description="MyAddin.MyAddinClass" />
</Class>
<File Id="filCC4172BEC1312562EDEF49648E45AE0D" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\MyAddin\bin\Debug\MyAddin.dll" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{10BC65F1-32C0-3ED4-98A0-17661A8C4455}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}" Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{10BC65F1-32C0-3ED4-98A0-17661A8C4455}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0" Name="Class" Value="MyAddin.MyAddinClass" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{10BC65F1-32C0-3ED4-98A0-17661A8C4455}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0" Name="Assembly" Value="MyAddin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{10BC65F1-32C0-3ED4-98A0-17661A8C4455}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="v4.0.30319" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{10BC65F1-32C0-3ED4-98A0-17661A8C4455}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0" Name="CodeBase" Value="file:///[#filCC4172BEC1312562EDEF49648E45AE0D]" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{10BC65F1-32C0-3ED4-98A0-17661A8C4455}\InprocServer32" Name="Class" Value="MyAddin.MyAddinClass" Type="string"Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{10BC65F1-32C0-3ED4-98A0-17661A8C4455}\InprocServer32" Name="Assembly" Value="MyAddin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{10BC65F1-32C0-3ED4-98A0-17661A8C4455}\InprocServer32" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="v4.0.30319" Type="string" Action="write" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{10BC65F1-32C0-3ED4-98A0-17661A8C4455}\InprocServer32" Name="CodeBase" Value="file:///[#filCC4172BEC1312562EDEF49648E45AE0D]" Type="string" Action="write" />
```

The component including this stuff has the Win64Flag tag set to yes. Therefore I thought things will be written to the x64 part of the registry. Until this, i read following article about [registry reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384235%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) telling this:

> For example, the 32-bit InprocServer32 key is not relevant for 64-bit applications, so the InprocServer32 key is not reflected to the 64-bit registry view.

Furthermore:

> However, 64-bit applications can use the 32-bit LocalServer32 key and the LocalServer32 key gets reflected.

But I already tried to use LocalServer32 instead of InprocServer32, but doing this, won't let my add in start on both platforms.

Will I have to use a call to [RegAsm Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or I'm missing a some tag or Interop registration option for x64 Platforms? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

With wix you need to do two things to disable registry reflection:

1. Mark your component as 64 bit component (attribute Win64="yes") (as you did)
2. Build your package as 64 bit package (Platform = x64)

This package won't be usable on x86 systems. So you will need two packages, one for x86 and one for x64. You can use the same source file for both packages as the Win64 attribute is ignored by the x86 package.